# Is there a way for converting WCF service into Azure Cloud Service without dealing with project files

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Here is my situation.

We provide Platform and `SDK` to other people where they can build `WCF` services and deploy that on site. We have a  many `ISVs` who has built wcf services, packaged them and ship them.

Packaging consist of couple of manifest file and `.dll` file that make up wcf service. Now we want to go on cloud with our platform.

Long story short - I have all the `dlls` for my wcf service but no project file.

Is there a way to generate cloud service package from this `dll` files?

Comment: How is the WFC services in these DLLs hosted?

Comment: we host wcf in IIS. is that what you are asking?

Comment: It uses this to host the service : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816902(v=vs.110).aspx